# "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" in Python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion, data-analysis

I'm currently taking a Data Analysis course on Udacity. I'm having a bit of hard time. I have I'm currently trying to convert some data types in some dictionaries and I keep getting the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" Now, it says it's a list but from my understanding all my data is in a dictionary. Here's the code.

```
# Lesson 1 - Data Analysis
# Get & Open Data
import unicodecsv
import datetime as dt

def openCSV(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)
        return list(reader)

def parse_date(date):
    if date == '':
        return None
    else:
        return dt.strptime(date, "%y-%m-%d")
def parse_int(i):
    if i == '':
        return None
    else:
        return int(i)

enrollments = openCSV("enrollments.csv")

for enrollment in enrollments:
    enrollments['cancel_date'] = parse_date(enrollments['cancel_date'])
    enrollments['days_to_cancel'] = parse_int(enrollments['days_to_cancel'])
    enrollments['is_canceled'] = enrollments['is_canceled'] == 'True'
    enrollments['is_udacity'] = enrollments['is_udacity'] == 'True'
    enrollments['join_date'] = parse_date(enrollments['join_date'])

# daily_engagement = openCSV("daily_engagement.csv")
# project_submissions = openCSV("project_submissions.csv")

enrollments[0]
```

Here is a sample of the contents of the file, it's the first two rows:

```
account_key,status,join_date,cancel_date,days_to_cancel,is_udacity,is_canceled
448,canceled,2014-11-10,2015-01-14,65,True,True
```

Comment: The last line of `openCSV` converts your data into a list, doesn't it? Try just returning `reader`

Comment: I thought the line `reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f)` converted the data to a dictionary. Mainly because you cannot access an item in a list with a string. @SimonFraser

Comment: in your for loop, you get enrolment by iterating on enrolments, but you try to access enrolements keys instead of enrollment keys

Comment: You may simply print out `enrollment` in each iteration to verify your assumption. You may also include full stack trace to show us exactly where error is raised. Why guess and assume if you can check and know?

Comment: Oh that's a great point @Apero! I'll try that.

Comment: can you edit your question and add the content of enrollments with only the first enrollment dict, to help me understand because I can't anymore...

Comment: Does that help any better @Apero ?

Comment: Yes, it shows me that the code works with my changes, and breaks otherwise, but I used csv.DictReader on my machine

Comment: Thank you for the help @Apero , I got it to work finally. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

in your for loop, you get enrolment by iterating on enrolments, but you try to access enrollments keys instead of enrollment keys

```
for enrollment in enrollments:
    enrollment['cancel_date'] = parse_date(enrollment['cancel_date'])
    enrollment['days_to_cancel'] = parse_int(enrollment['days_to_cancel'])
    enrollment['is_canceled'] = enrollment['is_canceled'] == 'True'
    enrollment['is_udacity'] = enrollment['is_udacity'] == 'True'
    enrollment['join_date'] = parse_date(enrollment['join_date'])
```

Also, your helper functions can be simplified:

```
def parse_date(date):
    return dt.strptime(date, "%y-%m-%d") if date else None

def parse_int(i):
    return int(i) if i else None
```

Comment: So, I changed it so it returned a dictionary instead of a list and used the code above. I get a new error though. ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required

Comment: do not change how you built enrollments, just remove the "s" as I did

Comment: I tried that as well, it gives me the same error that I started with, TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str.

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo. It should be `enrolment['cancel_date']` not `enrolments['cancel_date']`